# Не работает слайдер на сайте в консоле 53 ошибки Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Tags: javascript, php, css, jquery, modx

На [сайте](https://csm-spb.ru/) был слайдер, не кто него не трогал как и весь сайт в целом.
В один прекрасный день перестал работать слайдер, зашел в консоль и там OVER много [ошибок](https://prnt.sc/mq0i4v).
Сам слайдер:

```
<section class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 solutions"id="object" style="background: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #928f8f, #fff);">
    <div class="container">
       <h3 class="clearfix hidden-xs" style="color:#ffffff; position:relative; top:0px;font-family: Georgia;font-weight: normal; clear:both;">Решения </h3>
        <div class="carousel-container hidden-xs">
            <div id="carousel">
                <div class="carousel-feature">
                    <a href="#"><img class="carousel-image" alt="Материалы для строительства спортивных сооружений" src="assets/img/slider/Zenit_stadion.jpg">
                    </a>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <p>
                            Материалы для строительства/ремонта спортивных сооружений
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-feature">
                    <a href="#"><img class="carousel-image" alt="Материалы для ремонта транспортных сооружений" src="assets/img/slider/Puteprovod_avtomobil'nyy.jpg">
                    </a>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <p>
                            Материалы для строительства и ремонта транспортных сооружений
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-feature">
                    <a href="#"><img class="carousel-image" alt="Материалы для закрепления грунта" src="assets/img/slider/Zakrepleniye_grunta_Pskov.jpg">
                    </a>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <p>
                            Материалы для закрепления грунта
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-feature">
                    <a href="#"><img class="carousel-image" alt="Подливка металлоконструкций, оборудования" src="/assets/img/slider/Podlivka_opory.jpg">
                    </a>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <p>
                            Материалы для высокоточной цементации металлоконструкций
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-feature">
                    <a href="#"><img class="carousel-image" alt="Материалы для ремонта очистных сооружений" src="assets/img/slider/Shakhta_kanalizatsionnaya.jpg">
                    </a>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <p>
                             Материалы для гидроизоляции подземных сооружений
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-feature">
                    <a href="#"><img class="carousel-image" alt="Восстановление гидроизоляции подземных сооружений" src="assets/img/slider/Torkret-beton.jpg">
                    </a>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <p>
                             Торкрет-бетон, готовая сухая смесь
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-feature">
                    <a href="#"><img class="carousel-image" alt="Восстановление защитного слоя бетона, механизированное нанесение" src="assets/img/slider/Materialy_dlya_gidroizolyatsii_podzemnykh_sooruzheniy.jpg">
                    </a>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <p>
                            Материалы для ремонта очистных сооружений
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="carousel-feature">
                    <a href="#"><img class="carousel-image" alt="Восстановление защитного слоя бетона, механизированное нанесение" src="/assets/img/slider/Materialy_dlya_vysokotochnoy_tsementatsii_oborudovaniya.jpg">
                    </a>
                    <div class="carousel-caption">
                        <p>
                           Материалы для высокоточной цементации оборудования
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="carousel-left"><img src="/assets/img/slider/left.png" title="LEFT" />
            </div>
            <div id="carousel-right"><img src="/assets/img/slider/right.png" title="RIGHT" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

Подскажите как это исправить.
Движок сайта modx

Comment: Проверьте содержимое папки `assets` со стилями и скриптами

Comment: Все на месте, это то и удивительно.

Comment: И так я смог восстановить работу слайдера и убрать ошибки. Через костыли, но все-же. <br>Сначала исправил все ошибки про которые говорил валидатор, не помогло. Потом - зашел на сервер через FTP сказал папку `assets/js/`, зашел в файловый менеджер через CMS создал в папке `assets` папку `jsc`. Загрузил туда все необходимые скрипты и изменил путь в шаблоне. Работает, если кто то подскажет как сделать все по нормальному, буду очень благодарен.

Answer (score 1):

Много 404 ошибок, проверьте наличие и целостность следующих файлов: https://monosnap.com/file/UEiV15rjjOnvlMw0qFA7J1pk8EiuY2

Comment: Я проверил они на месте. права папки 700
https://www.evernote.com/shard/s605/client/snv?noteGuid=e75fa11f-06ab-4cd8-ba3d-12e013809f0d&noteKey=4e3de10adae28c0c&sn=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.evernote.com%2Fshard%2Fs605%2Fsh%2Fe75fa11f-06ab-4cd8-ba3d-12e013809f0d%2F4e3de10adae28c0c&title=number-pb.js%2B%25D0%25B8%2Bcsm-spb.ru%2B%25D0%25B8%2Bmapei-spb.ru%2B-%2Bsftp%253A%252F%252Fcb88675%2540176.57.210.4%2B-%2BFileZilla%2B%25D0%25B8%2Bprogress-bar

Answer (score 1):

На вашем месте, я бы начал устранять все [ошибки](https://validator.w3.org/nu/?showsource=yes&showoutline=yes&showimagereport=yes&doc=https%3A%2F%2Fcsm-spb.ru%2F). Уверен, после их исправления, все будет работать корректно.

Comment: Я сел и исправил все ошибки теперь там только предупреждение на type="text/javascript" , это вроде не на что не влияет. Работать слайдер от этого не стал.(

Comment: Валидность кода не имеет никакого отношения к ошибкам 404. Не ответ на вопрос

Comment: @andreymal в чем тогда может быть проблема?

Comment: @andreymal Вы ошибаетесь. В коде было море ошибок, в том числе и не закрытые теги, причем не просто не закрытые, а вот такого вида: `<div class="class" <div class="other"` и так во всем. Возможно это совпадение, но, на текущий момент 404 ошибки по файлам исчезли.

Comment: @ДмитрийПоленов сейчас у вас нет 404 ошибок по файлам

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev нельзя судить по внешним ссылкам, возможно автор просто загрузил на сервер все нужные файлы. Это совпадение, ошибки 404 просто технически не могут иметь никакого отношения к валидности кода, какой бы некорректный он ни был

Comment: @andreymal он присылал скрин, в котором была показана папка со всем содержимым. В общем-то, тут нет смысла спорить, не зная дальнейших действий автора. Один пропущенный символ мог неверно передавать весь остальной код браузеру. И я не писал, что это однозначное решение вопроса, я лишь написал, что поиск необходимо начать с устранения ошибок кода.

Comment: @AlexeyGiryayev ответы на Stack Overflow должны быть однозначным решением вопроса

Comment: @andreymal дело в том что если зайти по ftp на сервак они есть, если через менеджер файлов в CMS этой папки нет. Очень похоже на то что проблема в настройке CMS. В комментарии под основным постом я писал как частично я это решил